# If $x,y \in X$, then $[x] \cap [y] =\emptyset$ or $[x]=[y]$ for $ [x]= \cap \lbrace A \in \mathcal{M} \:|\: x \in A \rbrace$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $X$ be a non empty set, and $(X, \mathcal{M})$ a measurable space. Then I define

$$ [x]= \cap \lbrace A \in \mathcal{M} \:|\: x \in A \rbrace$$.

At my class my teacher told us to prove that:

If $x,y \in X$, then $[x] \cap [y] =\emptyset$ or $[x]=[y]$.

I have just made a simple attempt to this as if $[x] \cap [y] =\emptyset$ we are done if $[x] \cap [y]  \neq \emptyset$ but Im having issues to  continue here as Im not sure how to express $u \in [x] \cap [y]$ in order to conclude $[x]=[y]$.

Comment: This definition does not make sense to me. Over what does the intersection runs, i. e., what is the index of the intersection? $\{ A \in \mathcal{M} : x \in A \}$ is one set, so $\cap \{ A \in \mathcal{M} : x \in A \} =  \{ A \in \mathcal{M} : x \in A \}$.

Comment: @Jan A measurable space is, essentially, a set of sets (with some properties). So we are looking for the intersection of all of the sets $A$ (which belong to that set of sets $\cal M$) containing a particular element $x$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop The set $\{ A \in \mathcal{M} : x \in A \}$ is the set of all sets which contain $x$. If you take the intersection on this set, you simply get this again, since it is one set. What you have described, has to be written as $[x] = \cap_i A_i$, where $A_i$ are the sets containing $x$.

Comment: @Jan I didn't mind the OP's notation, it was clear to me. Possibly $\bigcap_{A\in\cal{M},x\in A}A$ could be what you are after. ($\cap_i A_i$ is unclear, because it is not clear what is $i$ - there is no notion that the set $\cal M$ is indexed.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes, $\bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{M}: x \in A} A$ is what I understand of the intersection of all sets containing $x$. What OP has written is definitely not this, since this is the intersection about the ONE AND ONLY set which contains all sets containing $x$.

Comment: @Jan To give some credit to the OP, I believe the notation they used is not unheard of: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_intersections (Set theorists would sometimes write "$\cap M$"...). My answer below also assumes that meaning. Hope if the OP meant anything else, they would comment.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $u\in[x]$. Then we have:

- If a measurable set $A$ contains $x$, it contains $u$.
- If a measurable set $A$ does not contain $x$, it cannot contain $u$, because, otherwise, the measurable set $A'$ would contain $x$ but not $u$.

This means that: $(\forall A\in{\cal M})(x\in A\Leftrightarrow u\in A)$, so the intersections defining $[x]$ and $[u]$ are the intersections of the same set of sets. Thus $[u]=[x]$.

An obvious consequence: if $u\in[x]\cap[y]$, then $[u]=[x]$ and $[u]=[y]$, i.e. $[x]=[y]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But still I dont see clear how these two points implies $[u]=[x]$. I cannot prove neither contention. Aprecciate if you can develope the details there.  @Stinking Bishop

Comment: @Cos So if we have proven this: $(\forall A\in{\cal M})(x\in A\Leftrightarrow u\in A)$ then it means that the intersections defining $[x]$ and $[u]$ will be the intersections of the same set of sets - so the result of intersection (i.e. $[x]$/$[u]$) will be the same. I have edited the answer to state that.